# Terrain normal has wrong direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to rotate my player along surface. Like transform.up = ground.normal

So now I'm debugging GetInterpolatedNormal() and it always has the same direction. Could you help me with that?

Code reference: https://answers.unity.com/questions/868898/make-gameobject-always-vertical-to-terrain.html

```
 private Vector3 SampleNormal()
    {
        var terrain = Terrain.activeTerrain;
        var terrainLocalPos = transform.position - terrain.transform.position;
        var normalizedPos = new Vector2(
            Mathf.InverseLerp(0f, terrain.terrainData.size.x, terrainLocalPos.x),
            Mathf.InverseLerp(0f, terrain.terrainData.size.z, terrainLocalPos.z)
        );
        var terrainNormal = terrain.terrainData.GetInterpolatedNormal(normalizedPos.x, normalizedPos.y);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, terrainNormal, Color.red, 5f);

        return terrainNormal;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Your Debug.DrawRay appears to be pointing in the right direction, though it's hard to tell from the pic. Is that the angle you want? If so the problem will be in the character movement script.

Comment: @Absinthe no, i want to debug NORMAL to the terrain surface instead of this i get the same ray looking always up

Comment: Unity help page for that method is a laff: "GetInterpolatedNormal. Description: Gets an interpolated normal". Thanks :). Anyway I found this, seems to be a clean solution: https://answers.unity.com/questions/358376/whats-a-good-way-to-find-the-ground-normal.html